# Open Google tasks page in webview inside app

Tags: android, webview, google-tasks

In my app I want to open Google tasks page in `WebView`. (https://mail.google.com/tasks/android or https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas (second link most relevant for me, cause I use tablet)).

But when I load url:

```
wv.loadUrl(url);
```

My app open native browser and show nested page on it.

Then I tried open page in `WebView` inside app, with setting custom `WebViewClient` with

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```

And page opened inside app, but without binding Google account.

Is this possible to open some of this two pages in `WebView` inside my own app with binding Google acc (auto or not (I have all Google account info)).

**UPD**

**I'm looking for way, how make my `WebView` authorized in Google, with using `AccountManager`. I already can generate nested scope (like "ya....").**

ps - My app - already authorized in google, and Task Api available.

**UPD2**

**If it's possible I want to manage my authorization status. That mean: I can make my `WebView` authorized in Google and also unauthorized.**

Comment: check my below answer and let me know if you are looking for the same or not. I didnt tried this before but may be it will help you.

Comment: I know it's laaaaate, but does answer to this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451059/login-google-account-in-webview-using-account-manager-token

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, Hope you are looking for the same.

check below link:

[how to use the Google credentials stored on the device to log in to Google Web sites automatically](http://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2012/11/sso-using-account-manager.html)

another link:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android

but I would not prefer you to use this because of it is deprecated.

**EDIT:**

[Sample code found for the web view](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps)

> A lot of sites asks the user whether to remember the login state. If
>   the user chooses to remember, the next time the user returns to the
>   site, the site will not require the user to login. This is supported
>   by most web browsers. If you want the WebViewActivity has the same
>   function, you can use CookieSyncManager and CookieManager to do the
>   job. First, when you create your main activity, create a
>   CookieSyncManager with the application context also.

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for answer. About "open url in your app" already work code, from my question. The main problem for me now - how to authorize in webview. Unfortunately your link doesn't help me.

Comment: I also checked new url. The way to create request to google to receive tasks - clear for me. Now I trying open current links in webview. Main problem, that my webview non authorized in google yet, and users must enter thiers login/pass again. I'm looking for solution how create my webview authorized in google with using AccountManager of oauthToken like : "ya-.....".

Comment: check my edited answer. I have added link of sample code for web view authentication.

Comment: thanks for your time. But all what you advise, I tried. The main problem - user MUST enter their login/password. And this is critical for me. I have no idea, why I can't use Account Manager to pass account to -> WebView -> Google. But +1 for your scrupulousness. Thanks

Comment: welcome, I think it should be any way to do this. let me find it. :)